# Eloquent (Laravel) as a standalone - 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Below is my implementation, I'm using Eloquent standalone:

```
// create users table   
Capsule::schema()->create('users', function($table) use ($settings) {

    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->collation = $settings['settings']['eloquent']['collation'];
    
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('first_name', 64);
    $table->string('last_name', 64);
    $table->string('username', 32)->unique();
    $table->string('password', 128);
    $table->string('email', 255)->unique();
    
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes('deleted_at', 0);

});

// create users table   
Capsule::schema()->create('auth_tokens', function($table) use ($settings) {

    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->collation = $settings['settings']['eloquent']['collation'];
    
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('selector', 16)->unique();
    $table->string('token', 64);
    
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->dateTime('expire', 0);
    
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes('deleted_at', 0);

});
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php:449 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(449): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(640): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}('alter table `au...', Array) #2 /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(607): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('alter table `au...', Array, Object(Closure)) #3 /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(450): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('alter table `au...', Array, Object(Closure)) #4 /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Schema/Blueprint.php(83): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement('alter table `au...') #5 /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Schema/Builder.php(239): Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint->build(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection), Object(Ill in /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php on line 647
```

I've checked the documentation, and guessing the order is correct (users first, then auth_tokens). Any ideas?

Comment: `increments` does not make a big integer, it makes a regular integer ... you have to match the column type exactly for the foreign key to what it references

Comment: This seems to match `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();` and not seeing the error anymore. Thanks

Comment: @Martyn just so you know, there is `bigIncrements` as well. bigIncrements produces bigIntegers.